# how do i send a private message to all people who have a certain role? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to create a command that works like this

`<command> <roleName> <message>`

and sends the message privately to all discord users with the specified role

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Role.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Role?scrollTo=members) property.

```js
// get role by name
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '<roleName>');

// send a message to everyone with the role
role.members.each(user => user.send('This is a DM'));
```

---

This method assumes you have a way to get the `<roleName>` value from a string; perhaps with an `args` variable.